# ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'‏

Tags: deep-learning, faster-rcnn

```
image_data = []
 for index in range(len(annotations_bbox[:10])):
  img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/images/'+annotations_bbox['image_path'][index])
  image_data.append(img)
  height, width, channel = img.shape
  print(f"Image: {img.shape}")
```

I'm trying to run this code on google colab and it shows this error
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'‏

changed the path, adding for loop

Answer (score 0):

Probably path is not valid. Check the output of `print('/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/images/'+annotations_bbox['image_path'][index])` and in colab go to an image file, and copy path. Make sure they are the same. If not, fix it